# Django : python pandas generating blank excel

Tags: django, excel, pandas

I am using pandas tool to create downloadable  excel file.Excel will get it data from SQL table , which in turn will get populated depending on values entered by user.I have attached one download button in my web page to download the excel.

On clicking download button it's generating a blank excel file with sheet name and file name as **Consistency Report**. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance

**views.py**

```
def  export_excel(request):
response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=Consistency Report.xls'
fname = 'Consistency Report.xls'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};SERVER=******;DATABASE=testing;UID=***;PWD=******')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from dhm_consis_report_tbl")
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
data=cursor.fetchall()
cursor.commit()
print(columns)
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    data[i]=tuple(data[i]) 
df = ps.DataFrame(data=data,columns=columns)
writer = ps.ExcelWriter('Consistency Report.xls',engine='xlwt')
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Report')
writer.save()

return response
```

So, I edited my views.py and am able to generate and download excel file but the problem is that the file is now downloading at two locations; one at my project folder and one at my download folder.Also the file at download folder is empty while the one at my project folder contains data.Can anybody explain why this is happening?

**Modified views.py**

```
def  export_excel(request):

response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=Consistency Report.xls'
df = ps.DataFrame.from_records(DHM_Consis_Report.objects.values('conquery_source','conquery_name','conquery_count','conquery_desc','criticality','sp_status','con_rundate','instance_id'))
print(df)
writer = ps.ExcelWriter('Consistency Report.xls',encoding='utf-8')
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Report')
writer.save()
return response
```

Comment: Basically you need to send the generated file "Consistency Report.xls", you can do it by reading it into the response's body or using another alternative like sendfile or filetransfers.

Comment: @Rho Can you explain how to do that. Django noob so any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think one quick and dirty way could be: `response.content = open("Consistency Report.xls")` just before  `return response`. But this assumes your file is small enough to fit into memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to generate required excel.Earlier I was creating and writing the excel with data but my HttpResponse was not getting the required data.I put the logic regarding generating excel in separate function and logic regarding downloading the generated file in separate function.This is what I did.

I  know it's crude and inefficient but this works for me.If anyone has better way to do this please share.

**views.py**

```
 @login_required
def consisreports(request):
    cust= customername
    username=None
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        username=request.user.username
    print(username)    
    table=ConsisReport(DHM_Consis_Report.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request,paginate={"per_page": 25}).configure(table)
    todays=date.today()
    todays=todays.strftime("%d-%m-%y")
    filename="Consistency Report %s as on %s %s.xls"%(cust,str(todays),username)
    colname=['Customer','Query ','Count','Desc','Criticality','Status','Rundate','Instance ID']
    df = ps.DataFrame.from_records(DHM_Consis_Report.objects.values('conquery_source','conquery_name','conquery_count','conquery_desc','criticality','sp_status','con_rundate','instance_id'))
    df=df[['conquery_source','conquery_name','conquery_count','conquery_desc','criticality','sp_status','con_rundate','instance_id']]
    print(df)
    #df.save('C:/Users/P1097/Desktop')
    writer = ps.ExcelWriter(filename)
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Report',index=False,engine='xlsxwriter',header=colname)
    writer.save()
    return render(request, 'consistency/consresult.html', {'table': table,'customername':cust})


@login_required       
def  export_excel(request):
    custname=customername
    username=None
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        username=request.user.username
    todays=date.today()
    todays=todays.strftime("%d-%m-%y")
    filename="Consistency Report %s as on %s %s.xls"%(custname,str(todays),username)
    wrapper=open(filename,"rb")
    cont=wrapper.read()
    response = HttpResponse(cont,content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8")
    response['Content-Length']=os.path.getsize(filename)
    size=os.path.getsize(filename)
    print(size)
    wrapper.close()
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename= %s'%filename
    return response
```